# Read text from an arabic newspaper in Python

Tags: python, arabic

I have an Arabic newspaper with a somewhat complex layout, first thing is that it uses a two columns layout and tables,

here is an example of a page:
[image]

the first thing I tried is PyPDF2:

```
reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(listOfPdfs[3])
page = reader.pages[0]
page.extract_text().replace('\n', '<br>')
```

some lines are spelled backwards, and the table is not correctly ordered but it at least starts reading the text from the right column first the left one.

another solution is ocr:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

pdf_path = listOfPdfs[3]
images = convert_from_path(pdf_path)
from pytesseract import image_to_string

for image in images[:1]:
    text = image_to_string(image, lang='ara')
    print("------------\n"+text.replace('\n', '<br>'))
```

this one reads the lines correctly, but it completley ignorded the table and the two columns layout (it just reads whatever is at the current horizontal line), and since I am telling the ocr this is an arabic text it interprets French text as Arabic

so the goal for me is to read the text while respecting the layout (from right to left, and right column before the left)

link to the pdf file in the example: https://mega.nz/file/VSZDhb6b#FPCDNH1XS-_SgjSTErWWjV4mEAEQ7xlSV2D0nWdeJRI